# Mask password text beneath title

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm trying to get the text beneath the title masked, so that it doesn't show the password (see image, where it says "mask this").

Anyone have an idea of how to change it so that the text is masked with "**" or even dots.

Regards.

**Edit:** setting android:password="true" doesn't work.

In my XML i have the following:

```html
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <EditTextPreference
        android:key="Username"
        android:id="@+id/brugerNavn"
        android:title="@string/pref_title_display_name"
        android:defaultValue="@string/pref_default_display_name"
        android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:capitalize="words"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:maxLines="1" />

    <EditTextPreference
        android:key="Password"
        android:id="@+id/passWord"
        android:title="@string/password"
        android:defaultValue=""
        android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:maxLines="1" />

    <CheckBoxPreference
        android:title="Invert swipe"
        android:defaultValue="false"
        android:key="invertCheckBox">
    </CheckBoxPreference>

</PreferenceScreen>
```

[image: The place to hide it]

Comment: Can't you just do a manual obfuscation? Create a string as long as the real password, and then just fill it with *?

Comment: Just as I posted this, I figured it out - but thanks for the reply anyways! :)